# Sphinx 4 configuration VoxForge

Tags: java, speech-recognition, sphinx4

I was able to walk through Sphinx4 tutorials, but now I need to integrate Voxforge with it and I can't find any tutorials or blogposts on that matter!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps

---

Official documentation for integrating VoxForge into Sphinx 4
[How to Use Models from SphinxTrain in Sphinx-4](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/doc/UsingSphinxTrainModels.html)

---

*Also See*
[Creating Sphinx Acoustic Models](http://www.voxforge.org/home/forums/message-boards/acoustic-model-discussions/creating-sphinx-acoustic-models/8)
[Use VoxForges Sphinx acoustic model with Sphinx4?](http://www.voxforge.org/home/forums/message-boards/speech-recognition-engines/use-voxforges-sphinx-acoustic-model-with-sphinx4)
[Sphinx3 model to Sphinx4 model](http://www.voxforge.org/home/forums/other-languages/russian/sphinx3-model-to-sphinx4-model/2)